# Pandas Array memory

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, memory

everybody. We are building a book recommendation system. We have several columns. We have added these columns together. After stacking the columns, calculating their cosine similarity. At this point there are about 100,000 x 100,000 rows and columns, and python throws an out-of-memory error (unable to allocate due to out-of-memory). We want to insert it into the pandas array. It showed insufficient 100+ gb for allocation. Need advice from those who have helped and solved this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of dataset need 100K columns?

Comment: This seems like something that should be in a database, not pandas.

Comment: Related [How to reduce amount of ram used by pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73951895/how-to-reduce-amount-of-ram-used-by-pandas/73952156#73952156)